# Menu click (or right click) on a image and add black border in Mac OSX (Snow Leopard)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macruby

I wrote a MacRuby script to apply some border to image. But I can't figure out how to make something like a menu-click (right click) on a image and run the script to apply the effect to the image.

Where/what do I need to RTFM? Or has anybody got some code sample I can learn from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop a contextual menu plugins for Finder. I'm sure you will find lots of info about such a plugin in here or on Google.